# Rest Https Server Using Visual C++ 2017

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2017, webserver, restbed

I want to implement a simple REST https server using visual studio 2017 (Windows 10). I used [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) with [this](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/documentation/example/HTTPS_SERVICE.md) code. But I got this error:

'rested::Http': HTTP client is deprecated; we will release a complimentary client framework at a future date.

I searched for a solution, but I found nothing.
Does anyone have any idea about this or any other suggestions for this problem?

Comment: It would help if you provided a bit code.

Comment: Alter the build script to mark the error as a warning.